# How do I display an array with indexes. I am acquiring the array from an HTTP GET request

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to display a list of categories. I used `*ngFor` to get the array into the `ion-list`. my array is acquired from an `HTTP GET` request. but the data from the server has indexes and I am unable to display all the data in the array. I have attached my `home.ts` and `home.html` and the `console.log`

**home.ts:**

```
  private products = [];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  get_products() {
    this.httpClient.get("http://test.vazy.co.ke/api-categories").subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res["data"];

      console.log(this.products);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        this.products[i];
      }
    });
  }
```

**home.html:**

```
<button (click)="get_products()">GET /products</button>
<ion-list *ngFor="let product of products">
  <ion-text>
    {{ product[i] }}
  </ion-text>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: please share the response from http://test.vazy.co.ke/api-categories

Comment: they are in a console.log message below. i tried inserting them here but they were too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `*ngFor="let product of products; let i of index;"` to get index.

and `{{ product }}` will automatically print the indexed value.

for example `products = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];`

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products"> {{ product }} </li>
</ul>

// output
<ul>
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
    <li> c </li>
</ul>
```

and if your products variable contain `products = [{ name: 'a', name: 'b', name: 'c' }]`

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products"> {{ product.name }} </li>
</ul>

// output
<ul>
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
    <li> c </li>
</ul>
```

---

Based on your products output created a demo

[Stackbliz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-ngforitration)

Comment: @skdroid..the data returned by the http get already has indexes.

Comment: here"s my json for console.log..0: {id: "1", name: "Dress", description: "Denim skirts etc", image: "1", created_at: "2019-06-11 11:18:48"}
1: {id: "2", name: "Shoes", description: "Quality Men, Female shoes", image: "2", created_at: "2019-06-11 12:55:22"}
2: {id: "3", name: "Jackets", description: "Classy and modern Jackets", image: "3", created_at:

Comment: like..if i wanted to display the name dress i'd type: {{products.name}} but now the index is blocking me..i have to type {{products["0"].name}}..and i can't do this for all the items..i'd like to loop it so that it can display the names and descriptions of all the three items at once without me typing {{products["1"].description}}

Comment: yes but *ngFor will iterate with index. based on your JSON I've created a demo please check the answer.

Comment: hey @skdroid..i can't see the demo..could you please highlight it for me?

Comment: okay..i'm getting the data from the server..and it returns it with indexes..so when i try outputing {{products.name}} nothing is displayed

Comment: could you add server data in your question. and use product.name not products.name

Comment: the json console.log above is my server response.

Comment: however, i have noted that on postman it doesn't number the items..how do i get my response not to number them? coz that's where my issue is.